Keycloack and Wildfly, connection closed after access token lifespan
I created a web application with Wildfly 30 (Jakarta EE10). Authentication works with Keycloak.
I use the annotation:
@OpenIdAuthenticationMechanismDefinition(
        providerURI = "${openIdConfig.providerUrl}",
        clientId = "${openIdConfig.clientId}",
        clientSecret = "${openIdConfig.clientSecret}",
        redirectURI = "${openIdConfig.redirectUrl}",
        claimsDefinition = @ClaimsDefinition(callerGroupsClaim = "roles"),
        logout = @LogoutDefinition(redirectURI = "/logout.html", notifyProvider = true)
)

In web.xml I defined <security-constraint> and  <security-role> and they all work as expected.
This works fine, but after the lifetime of the 'Access Token Lifespan' in Keycloak (5 minutes default) the session is closed and the user has to log in again. This happens even if the user is constantly requesting new pages.
How can I keep the user logged in until the session expires (30 minutes default).

It turns out that I have a class:
@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class JaxRsActivator extends Application {
}


That used to work fine before I implemented Jakarta securtity.
If I delete this class, the application runs fine, no more problems after 5 minutes. But of course, no more rest requests either.
When I add the annotation
@DeclareRoles({ "Admin",....})

the application runs fine also. And of course, rest requests work again fine.
So @DeclareRoles was missing.

Set the property @OpenIdAuthenticationMechanismDefinition.tokenAutoRefresh to true.

In my case, that ends with an exception. I have forgotten witch one.
